# I want to sort two parallel arrays, one is of String and the other of double data types

Tags: java, arrays

I'm relatively new to the programming scene and i would like you to assist me with sorting of these arrays. The idea is to display a menu item on a textArea and sort the items by name. The parralel arrays contain food items and the other one prices.

```
String[] items  = {"Gatspy", "Coffee", "Chicken", "Mango Juice"};
double[] prices = {8.99, 23.50, 29.90, 7.50};
```

Comment: Every 4th weekday, people come here wanting to sort parallel arrays. Every time, 6 people jump up and say: use a better data structure. (a) Why is this happening? Is this being taught in college or something (b) shall we appoint one of these as a FAQ?

Comment: That is a fair point -- I believe actually it is probably due to the lack of understanding of encapsulating the data. So probably somewhere in the FAQ's it should be stressed out that "before you do anything, think of data encapsulation and how well you have designed your data structures". There are occasionally reasons why one would use parallel arrays but this certainly doesn't seem to be one of those cases.

Answer (score 4):

Or how about encapsulating the item name and price in a class, then have a single array of instances of this class and use a `Comparator` to sort them?
E.g.

```
public class Item {
private String name;
private double price;
...
//getters and setters for name and price
}

...

Item []items = { new Item("Gatspy", 8.99), .... };

...

class ItemComparator implements Comparator {
 public int compare( Object o1, Object o2 ) {
  Item i1 = (Item)o1;
  Item i2 = (Item)o2;
  return i1.getName().compareTo(i2.getName());
 }
}

...

Arrays.sort( items, new ItemComparator() );
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use arrays in the first place, use a [`Map`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). In your case, use a [`TreeMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), it's sorted by its keys.

```
Map<String, Double> map = new TreeMap<String, Double>();
map.put("Gatspy", 8.99);
// put the other items
```

Now iterate over the entries:

```
for(Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : map.entrySet()){
    System.out.println("<option value=\"" 
                       + entry.getValue() 
                       + "\">" 
                       + entry.getKey() 
                       + "</option>");
}
```

**Reference:** [Java Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) > [Collections Trail](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) > [The Map Interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)

Comment: in general a `Map` would not work in case of duplicates, such as `{"Coffee", "Chicken", "Coffee"}` and `{5.99, 6.0, 2.35}`

Comment: @MarcoS Obviously. But we're talking about a menu, and that should never contain duplicate items!

Answer (score 0):

You should use objects:

```
public class Item {
    private String name;
    private double price; // you shouldn't use doubles for money, but this is unrelated

    public Item(String name, double price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return this.price;
    }
}
```

Then you may have an array (or a list) of Items :

```
private Item[] items = new Item[] {new Item("Gtaspy", 8.99), ...};
```

and you may sort this array using [Arrays.sort()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29) (or Collections.sort() if you use a List instead of an array).

Read the [Java tutorial on Collections](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html) for more details.

Comment: how can i then cater for new input as my program we'll also have new items added on the menu, will this sort the incoming data as well?

Comment: When a nex item if created through your application, create a new Item instance, add it at the end of the list, sort the list again, and redisplay the whole list.

Comment: thanks for you help guys but our lecturer insisted that we use  parallel arrays and display them on a JList. So when now i've managed to display the items arrays of String data type on the JList but i'm unable to display the prices array of double data type. here is how i did this: String [] items = {"Cheese burger ","Gatsby ","Cappuccino ","Hot wings ","Fish and chips ","Coffee ","Calamari "}; Arrays.sort(menu);
   foodList = new JList(items);//foodList is a JList object

Answer (score 0):

Possible approach could be the same as implemented in this math3 library:
**org.apache.commons.math3.util.MathArrays#sortInPlace**

```
/**
 * Sort an array in place and perform the same reordering of entries on
 * other arrays.  This method works the same as the other
 * {@link #sortInPlace(double[], double[][]) sortInPlace} method, but
 * allows the order of the sort to be provided in the {@code dir}
 * parameter.
 *
 * @param x Array to be sorted and used as a pattern for permutation
 * of the other arrays.
 * @param dir Order direction.
 * @param yList Set of arrays whose permutations of entries will follow
 * those performed on {@code x}.
 * @throws DimensionMismatchException if any {@code y} is not the same
 * size as {@code x}.
 * @throws NullArgumentException if {@code x} or any {@code y} is null
 * @since 3.0
 */
public static void sortInPlace(double[] x,
                               final OrderDirection dir,
                               double[] ... yList)
    throws NullArgumentException, DimensionMismatchException {
    if (x == null) {
        throw new NullArgumentException();
    }

    final int len = x.length;
    final List<Pair<Double, double[]>> list
        = new ArrayList<Pair<Double, double[]>>(len);

    final int yListLen = yList.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        final double[] yValues = new double[yListLen];
        for (int j = 0; j < yListLen; j++) {
            double[] y = yList[j];
            if (y == null) {
                throw new NullArgumentException();
            }
            if (y.length != len) {
                throw new DimensionMismatchException(y.length, len);
            }
            yValues[j] = y[i];
        }
        list.add(new Pair<Double, double[]>(x[i], yValues));
    }

    final Comparator<Pair<Double, double[]>> comp
        = new Comparator<Pair<Double, double[]>>() {
        public int compare(Pair<Double, double[]> o1,
                           Pair<Double, double[]> o2) {
            int val;
            switch (dir) {
            case INCREASING:
                val = o1.getKey().compareTo(o2.getKey());
            break;
            case DECREASING:
                val = o2.getKey().compareTo(o1.getKey());
            break;
            default:
                // Should never happen.
                throw new MathInternalError();
            }
            return val;
        }
    };

    Collections.sort(list, comp);

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        final Pair<Double, double[]> e = list.get(i);
        x[i] = e.getKey();
        final double[] yValues = e.getValue();
        for (int j = 0; j < yListLen; j++) {
            yList[j][i] = yValues[j];
        }
    }
}
```